# Why class extending intentservice needs empty constructor?

Tags: android

Could anybody explain it and help me to understand it.?

Comment: Not entirely sure but might be needed for some Reflection going on in the Android Framework

Comment: Who says it does need an empty constructor?

Answer (score 6):

All components (activities, services, content providers, and broadcast receivers) need an empty constructor, as that is how Android will attempt to create the object as needed. Android cannot use other constructors, because it has no way to know what to pass in as the parameter values.

Comment: Then why is the `IntentService` constructor documented as: `IntentService(String name)`?

Comment: @trojanfoe: That is the constructor supplied by the superclass. *You* need to implement a zero-argument constructor that *chains* to the one-argument superclass constructor, where that argument is a name used for logging AFAIK. Yes, this is annoying.

Comment: @CommonsWare: while extending the SQLiteOpenHelper, why it is necessary to create constructor of our Database class.

Comment: @AmarnathBaitha: I have no idea what your "Database class" is. I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question and explain your situation in more detail.